# Questions on Exception Specification and Application Design

Tags: c++, design-patterns, exception, try-catch

Although this topic has been extensively discussed on SO, I'd like to clarify a few things that are still not clear to me so, considering the following facts:

1. 10 years ago, Herb Sutter was telling us to [refrain from using this functionality](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm).
2. Specifying the possible exceptions that a function / method may throw does not force the compiler to yell at you when you decide to change the function's body and throw a new type of exception, forgetting by mistake to change the exception specification in the function's declaration.
3. If you have a very high level function that calls several other high level functions, which each run tons of code to produce the results, then I can imagine the maintenance from hell nightmare, when I would have to specify ALL the errors which the first function may throw, and this list would have to include all the exceptions the inner functions may throw and so on, thus creating tight coupling between high and low level functions, which is quite undesirable. On the other hand, we derive all exceptions from std::runtime_error, which [we know is a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158134/1174378) and we could specify that the high level functions just throw std::runtime_error and be done with it. But wait a minute... Where do we actually catch the exceptions? Would it not be rather odd / nasty / bad to enclose a call to one of these high level functions in a try / catch block, which catches a MyVerySpecific exception, when the high level function is supposed to throw only std::runtime_error??? Would it be any good to catch specific exceptions in lower level functions, which are not able to do anything about them but pass them on in a more generic container, with more information appended to them? I certainly don't want to write try / catch blocks in every function that I write, just to format exceptions. It would be like requiring every function to validate its parameters, and that can drive people insane, when they need to change something in a low level function.

Questions:

1. Do Herb Sutter's rants about exception specification still hold today? Has anything changed since then? I am mostly interested in pre-C++0x standards. If yes, I guess we can consider this topic closed.
2. Since it seems that the compiler mostly ignores these exception specifications, and when catching exceptions, in 99% of the cases, one would use `catch (const CustomException &ex)`, how would one specify that a function throws CustomException? `throw(CustomExecption)` or `throw (CustomException &)` or `throw (const CustomException &)`? I have seen all variations, and, although I would go for the first one, do the others make any sense / add any benefits?
3. How would one actually use this functionality, and, at the same time, avoid the fallacies illustrated in the above 3rd fact?
4. **EDIT:** Suppose that we're building a library. How will its users know what exceptions to expect, if we don't use exception specification? They will certainly not see what functions will be called internally by the API methods...

Comment: The same issues hold true now as then, and exception specifications have been explicitly deprecated in C++11. There's `noexcept` instead, which is about as sane as these sorts of systems get.

Comment: Thanks for the spelling correction :D I have added an additional question based on your comment.

Comment: Well, how would the library be used? Personally (and you may find this a bit masochistic) but I've always felt that a general purpose library should have a plain old C interface with structs and enums and little else. Return error codes instead of throwing exceptions. Sure, its a pain to consume this with C++, but it makes using it in any other language positively trivial. Then they can just browse the error code lists to see what will be going on. This also frees you to use whatever crazy programming styles you like internally. Just a thought.

Comment: Although that sounds like a decent approach, I'm not willing to implement it, honestly. I think we should instruct everybody to do better than that, rather than just propagate such old practices forever... Thinking about that just makes me cringe, reminding me of the "good ol' days" when I was writing a `void main ()` for everything, since I didn't know any better back then...

Comment: A DLL with a C interface can have its functions trivially inspected using a suitable symbol extractor. I can talk to it directly using (say) C# p/invoke with no additional glue logic. I don't need to know what language it is written in, and I don't need to know what it does with exceptions. These are all good things. If you're writing a specifically C++ only library then you may as well use C++ end to end, of course. In that case, you may as well just stick your documentation and custom exception classes in the shared header files.

Comment: ...given that exception specifications are not really any more useful than a documentation string say `// throws foo_exception`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1/ Do Herb Sutter's rants about exception specification still hold today? Has anything changed since then? I am mostly interested in pre-C++0x standards. If yes, I guess we can consider this topic closed.

Yes, they still hold.

Exceptions specifications are:

- half-way implemented (function pointers don't specify exceptions, for example)
- not checked at compile-time, but leading to termination at runtime !!

In general, I would be against exceptions specifications, because it causes a leak of implementation details. Look at the state of Java exceptions...

In C++ in particular ? Exceptions specifications are like shooting yourself in the foot since the tiniest error in documentation may lead to a `std::terminate` call. Note that almost all functions may throw a `std::bad_alloc` or a `std::out_of_range` for example.

*Note: Since C++11, `throw()` was deprecated and now with C++17 it is gone; instead, from C++17 on, the `noexcept(false)` specifier can be used. It is better supported in function pointers, but still leads to termination at run-time rather than errors at compile-time.*

---

> 2/ Since it seems that the compiler mostly ignores these exception specifications, and when catching exceptions, in 99% of the cases, one would use catch (const CustomException &ex), how would one specify that a function throws CustomException? throw(CustomExecption) or throw (CustomException &) or throw (const CustomException &)? I have seen all variations, and, although I would go for the first one, do the others make any sense / add any benefits?

The compiler does not ignore the exceptions specifications, it sets up very vigilant watchdogs (which axes) to make sure to kill your program in case you had missed something.

---

> 3/ How would one actually use this functionality, and, at the same time, avoid the fallacies illustrated in the above 3rd fact?

Your customer will appreciate if it stays informal, so the best example is:

```
void func(); // throw CustomException
```

and this lets you focus on the exceptions that matter too, and let "unimportant" exceptions slip through. If a consumer wants them all ? `catch(std::exception const& e)` works.

---

> 4/ EDIT: Suppose that we're building a library. How will its users know what exceptions to expect, if we don't use exception specification? They will certainly not see what functions will be called internally by the API methods...

Do they have to ?

Document what matters, `std::exception` or `...` take care of the unexpected.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will integrate your suggestions into the library that I am working on.

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` is a good example where exception specifications usually fails

Comment: With C++1, , th eproblem "half-way implemented (function pointers don't specify exceptions, for example)" is gone. Try this code in clang 3.8.0. int main()
{
    void (*p)() throw(int);
    void (*p1)() throw();
    //p1= p;
    
}

Comment: With C++17, the problem "half-way implemented (function pointers don't specify exceptions, for example)" is gone.  Even more, the assignment checks for compatibility.    You may try this code in clang 3.8.0.                                 int main()
{
    void (*p)() throw(int);
    void (*p1)() throw();
    //p1= p;
}

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Do Herb Sutter's rants about exception specification still hold today? Has anything changed since then?

I wouldn't call that a rant. He just pointed out problems related to exception specifications.

Yes, it still holds. As explained in the text, if a not specified exception is throw, the program terminates, and that is not acceptable for 99% applications.

> 1. how would one specify that a function throws CustomException?

```
class A
{
 //...
   void foo() throws( CustomException );
};
```

> 1. How would one actually use this functionality, and, at the same time, avoid the fallacies illustrated in the above 3rd fact?

By looking at the function declaration, the user knows which exceptions can be thrown. The problem is when a new exception needs to be thrown, then all functions declarations needs to be changed.

> 1. Suppose that we're building a library. How will its users know what exceptions to expect, if we don't use exception specification?

By reading the documentation.

Comment: But that still is error prone, because I can't really expect someone to figure out where one small change to a (low level) function propagates so that the exception documentation can be modified accordingly. It seems like a big mess, to be honest.

Comment: @MihaiTodor: it is a big mess, which is why it's best avoided. C++11 deprecate exceptions specifications (apart from the new `noexcept`) for a reason.