# C++ Class Contained Exception Handling

Tags: c++

I've been working with exception handling for a long while today.  I've figured out to get it to work if it's in a void function, but how do I handle functions that have to return a value. The last 3 lines in main are where the "issue" happens.  I found this link earlier to help me get this far, but my exception handling has to all be contained inside the class structure, so I can't have try/throw/catch in main. I'd like to understand what's going on. [1]: [What type of exception should I throw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157591/c-exception-handling)

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class out_of_range : public std::exception
{
private:
    std::string msg;

public:
    out_of_range(const std::string msg) : msg(msg){};
    ~out_of_range(){};

    virtual const char * what()
    {
        return msg.c_str();
    }
};
class divide
{
private:
    int a;
    int * _ptr;
public:
    divide(int r): a(r), _ptr(new int[a]) {};
    ~divide(){ delete[] _ptr; };

    int get(int index) const
    {
        try
        {       
            if (index < 0 || index >= a)
                throw out_of_range("Err");              
            else
                return _ptr[index];
        }
        catch (out_of_range & msg)
        {
            std::cout <<  msg.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    int &get(int index)
    {
        try
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= a)
                throw out_of_range("Err");
            else
                return _ptr[index];
        }
        catch (out_of_range & msg)
        {
            std::cout << msg.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() 
{
    divide test(6);
    for (int i(0); i < 6; ++i)
    {
        test.get(i) = i * 3;
        std::cout << test.get(i) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "test.get(10): " << test.get(10) << std::endl;
    test.get(3) = test.get(10);
    std::cout << "test.get(3): " << test.get(3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you catch exception in the `divide::get` method, it must somehow tell its caller that something went wrong. So implementation may look something like that:

```
class divide
{   
//.. 
    bool get(int nIndex, int* nResult);
//...
int main() 
//...
    int nRes = 0;
    if(!test.get(10, &nRes))
      cout << "Something is not right";
```

If there is many things that could go amiss, you could return some error code instead of `bool`. But if you use this method, there is no need in your exception class, you could simply return error without raising exception at all.